# How to Show error if value of an array is empty

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, dropdown

```
Array = {
  0 : { NAME: 'A' , PET :'DOG' , AGE : 'NINE' },  
  1 : { NAME: 'B' , PET :'CAT' , AGE : 'TEN' },  
  2 : { NAME: 'C' , PET :'TURTLE' , AGE : '' }  
}
```

Html **:**

```
<option ng-repeat='data in array' value="data.NAME"> {{data.PET}} </option>
```

So, if second(index) option is selected and click on a save button. I want to show an error saying age is empty.

I have an access to only Name because of value with val() and PET with text() in :selected

How to show an error if age is empty

Comment: First, you need an array. Your `Array` variable is an object.

Comment: Can't you just use a ternary?  -->  `{ (!data.Age) ? <>Show Your Error</> :  <>Other Thing to do </> }`

Comment: @TheHeadRush yes. It's an object.  It looks like this after getting from python in js

Comment: @Zak how do I get data.age is the question as it's drop down. So selected options value I gey in js with (#idofoption).val() in this data.name comes and with .text() data.pet comes.  How do I get selected option's data.age

Answer (score 0):

Few observations **:**

- Your `Array` variable is not holding an array, It is holding an object.
- Your `ng-repeat` syntax should be changed to handle the object of objects.

  ```
  <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in Array" value="value.NAME">
    {{value.PET}}
  </option>
  ```

On submit, You can check for `AGE` field value from the `Array` object against this selected value (`value.NAME`).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const obj = {
    0 : { NAME: 'A' , PET :'DOG' , AGE : 'NINE' },
    1 : { NAME: 'B' , PET :'CAT' , AGE : 'TEN' },
    2 : { NAME: 'C' , PET :'TURTLE' , AGE : '' }
}

const selectedValue = 'C';

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(innerObjKey => {
    if (innerObjKey === 'NAME' && obj[key][innerObjKey] === selectedValue) {
        !obj[key].AGE ? console.log('Age not found!') : console.log('Age found!')
    }
  })
})
```